# CKEditor -- seeing styles in editor window

Tags: ckeditor

I'd like a true WYSIWYG experience from CKEditor, but it seems that since the editor operates in an iframe, there's no way to have the styes that clients apply to their items appear as they should per a site's stylsheet within the editor port. That is, for example, text given an H1 markup appear with the browser's default style, not the styles that I have in my stylesheet.

Or is there a way to apply a stylesheet to the generated iframe that displays the editor instance?

Searches on "CKEditor styles" all turn up references to styling the editor (color scheme of the frame, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [config.contentsCss](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.contentsCss) = your stylesheet