# Wrap CKEditor window in extra markup layers?

Tags: ckeditor

Is there a way to wrap the editor window in extra layers of markup, so that I can simulate particular css contexts?

For example, I in my stylesheet, I might have a selector  like:

```
 .container #articleBody h2{/* some styles */},
```

But I'm applying CKeditor to a textarea that edits what goes into #articleBody, so I'd need a way to apply a wrapper around the editor container with an id of #articleBody, and a wrapper around that with a class called .container to get styles from my site's stylesheet to apply correctly within the CKEditor editing iframe.

(Note: This is a follow-up question to [CKEditor -- seeing styles in editor window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886160/ckeditor-seeing-styles-in-editor-window/5889275#5889275), but I felt the issue was significantly distinct enough to warrant its own question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [bodyId](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.bodyId) and [bodyClass](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.bodyClass), although they won't be enough for that selector.

The easiest option would be to use just

```
#articleBody h2{/* some styles */},
```

As the Id selector should be enough to scope that rule in the original page and you can use then the config.bodyId